# How to overlap one div on another div using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, primeng

I tried z-index :-1 and position:absolute both didn't worked.

How to fix issue.

Are there any other alternatives for overlapping.

```
<div *ngIf="allFiltersData.length > 0">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <div id="{{controls.fieldName}}_Text" style="border-style: groove;font-style: 14px;border-radius:3px;height: 100%;word-wrap: break-word;padding-left:10px;padding-top:4px;padding-bottom: 4px;font-size: 14px;color:#333333;vertical-align: middle;" tabindex=0 (click)="showList(controls.fieldDisplayName)" class="accordion">Select {{controls.fieldDisplayName}}</div>

        <div name='htmlMultiSelect' style="overflow:auto;border-style: groove;width: 300px;background-color: white; position: absolute;height:auto;max-height: 200px; white-space: nowrap;display: none;" id="{{controls.fieldDisplayName}}">
            <div style=" padding-left: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                <input type="checkbox" (click)="selectAllForMultiSelect(controls,$event,tab.name)" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;vertical-align:middle;" id="{{controls.fieldName}}_SelectAll">
                <input name="{{controls.fieldName}}" (keypress)="multiSelectSearch($event,tab.name,controls)" id="{{controls.fieldDisplayName}}_{{tab.name}}_Search" style="width: 200px;height: 30px;vertical-align:middle;" type="text">
            </div>
            <div name="customMultiSelectItems" style="padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 10px;" *ngFor="let val of fetchFilterValues(controls.fieldName,true)">
                <input type="checkbox" (click)="setSelectedData(controls.fieldControlType, controls.fieldName, {id:val.value.id,name:val.value.name},controls.dependentFilterName,$event,controls.fieldDisplayName,tab.name)" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;vertical-align:middle;" id="{{val.value.id}}_{{controls.fieldName}}_{{tab.name}}" name={{val.value.name}}_{{controls.fieldName}}_{{tab.name}}>
                <label tabindex=0 style="font-size:14px;color: #333333;vertical-align:middle;" for={{val.value.id}}_{{tab.name}}> {{val.value.name}}</label>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="OverlapThisSection" style="position:absolute">
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using above code.

Div with id `OverlapThisSection` needs to be overlapped.  I had set Div with name `htmlMultiSelect`  to `position:absolute`

Div with  id `OverlapThisSection` not getting overlapped by another  Div above to it.

**Update 1:**

Currently I'm getting view as below.

[image]

[image]

Actually I'm using primeng dropdown inside `OverlapThisSection` div.

`<p-dropdown>` not getting overlapped by it's top div.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Question will be closed if you're not sharing the code or what you have achieved to get this done. `Div` is block element so you don't have to do anything to get sit on the top, only the div should be inside another.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Also some indication of what this is supposed to look like..

Comment: Added code. Kindly check

Comment: @Chandrasekhar as you see in my code, you have to give the height for the first `div` only then the second div content will sit inside. otherwise it will sit on top of the first divs content.

Comment: This really looks like a document flow issue. If you have control of the html structure and output, which it looks like you do, then it would be better to just place the element where you need it.

Comment: -1 Your code just doesn't make sense when ran on snipped. You didn't even provide the desired output. so this is quite messy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I see this 2 different `div`s, so you can use `position:absolute;` and `top:20px;` to the second div.

```css
#OverlapThisSection {
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="allFiltersData.length > 0">
  <div style="width: 100%; height:50px;">
    <div id="{{controls.fieldName}}_Text" style="border-style: groove;font-style: 14px;border-radius:3px;height: 100%;word-wrap: break-word;padding-left:10px;padding-top:4px;padding-bottom: 4px;font-size: 14px;color:#333333;vertical-align: middle;" tabindex=0
      (click)="showList(controls.fieldDisplayName)" class="accordion">Select {{controls.fieldDisplayName}}</div>

    <div name='htmlMultiSelect' style="overflow:auto;border-style: groove;width: 300px;background-color: white; position: absolute;height:auto;max-height: 200px; white-space: nowrap;display: none;" id="{{controls.fieldDisplayName}}">
      <div style=" padding-left: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <input type="checkbox" (click)="selectAllForMultiSelect(controls,$event,tab.name)" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;vertical-align:middle;" id="{{controls.fieldName}}_SelectAll">
        <input name="{{controls.fieldName}}" (keypress)="multiSelectSearch($event,tab.name,controls)" id="{{controls.fieldDisplayName}}_{{tab.name}}_Search" style="width: 200px;height: 30px;vertical-align:middle;" type="text">
      </div>
      <div name="customMultiSelectItems" style="padding-top: 5px;padding-left: 10px;" *ngFor="let val of fetchFilterValues(controls.fieldName,true)">
        <input type="checkbox" (click)="setSelectedData(controls.fieldControlType, controls.fieldName, {id:val.value.id,name:val.value.name},controls.dependentFilterName,$event,controls.fieldDisplayName,tab.name)" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;vertical-align:middle;"
          id="{{val.value.id}}_{{controls.fieldName}}_{{tab.name}}" name={{val.value.name}}_{{controls.fieldName}}_{{tab.name}}>
        <label tabindex=0 style="font-size:14px;color: #333333;vertical-align:middle;" for={{val.value.id}}_{{tab.name}}> {{val.value.name}}</label>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="OverlapThisSection" style="position:absolute">Second div content
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Or another simple example, you don't have to use `z-index` for this:

```css
.first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  margin: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
</div>
<div class="second">
</div>
```

Comment: After using the styles mentioned,  second div itself hiding. I want to make Div 1 overlap Div 2.  With you CSS,  DIV 2 itself  not dispalyed

Comment: I have mentioned in my comment, you have to increase the height of first div, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/60r7pz3m/279/

Comment: Using top:30px hiding the control.  If I remove top:30px style, then I'm getting view as given in question.I'm getting view as given in second screenshot.

Comment: then there is another properties which is making to do so, by any chance you can create a snippet so that I can look into?

Comment: actually I'm using  primeng dropdown and didnt applied any specific styles to it. Even then it is not getting overlapped.